Unable to run certain python command from Cmake
I'm having following python code
    cmd = [
        "cmd.exe", "/c",
        "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvarsx86_amd64.bat", 
        "^&^&", "set", "PATH", ">", temp_file_path
    ]
    print(cmd)
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True)
    if result.returncode != 0:
        print(f"Error running vcvarsx86_amd64: {result.stderr.decode('utf-8')}")
        sys.exit(1)

If I run this python script from the console eveything works fine.
But if I run it from inside cmake using the following command:
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${PYTHON_CMD} script.py
        --input_file ${INPUT_FILE}.dll
        --output_file ${OUTPUT_FILE}.dll
    RESULT_VARIABLE result
    )

I got following error:
   ['cmd.exe', '/c', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvarsx86_amd64.bat', '^&^&', 'set', 'PATH', '>', 'C:\\Users\\MYKOLA~1.GER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpio00uuoh']
   Error running vcvarsx86_amd64: The input line is too long.
   The syntax of the command is incorrect.


I got where was the problem. It is in print:
print(cmd) # The input line is too long.
result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True)

